# How to detect if a player is PRECISELY above a command block

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've been trying for hours and I can't seem to figure this out. I need a command block to detect if a player is DIRECTLY above a command block. I've tried using @a[x=X,y=Y,z=Z] (with real coordinates obviously) and it just fires the command no matter where you are. And distance= won't work since it covers a spherical area. I need it to be only above the command block and nowhere else. I will also be using this for multiple command blocks if that helps at all maybe? might make it harder idk help pls

Comment: What exactly do you want? Any part of the hitbox above or center or...? Is 0.1 blocks higher allowed or not, ...? In any case, `dx` `dy` `dz` should be the solution. Or just `/execute if block`, depending on what you want.

Comment: Hey sorry if I wasn't clear, all I need is simply when I step on top of a certain block that has the command block under it, it triggers the command. Any part of the hitbox would be fine as long as it only activates when stepping on that one block and nowhere else around it. Perhaps I'm using the dx dy and dz wrong but when I tried they detect in a 2x2 rectangular area and not on just one block. I'm using it in a repeating command block with /execute

Comment: You'll need to figure out the exact decimal numbers for it. I can't currently do it myself, but it should be pretty easy (just tedious). Or maybe you can simply use a pressure plate.

Answer (score -1):

Try `execute if entity @p[x=1,y=2,z=3,dx=0,dy=1,dz=0] run (whatever command)`. You can have the coordinates set to be directly overtop of said block or wherever else you need them to be. The most precision I could get is if even the slightest part of their hitbox touches the area the condition is met. I also have only made it work by either requiring a redstone signal or being a repeating command block.

Edit: to avoid repeating the command (such as a teleport or a tellraw) several times you can use two command blocks. One is a repeating command block that tests for the condition and outputs to a comparator and from that into the next command block (or into redstone and a repeater if you need multiple commands issued). The commands I used in my game to verify this were as follows.

For the repeating command block: `execute if entity @p[x=176,y=65,z=153,dx=0,dz=0,dy=1]` and for the non repeating: `tellraw @a "yes"`. Obviously adjust your coordinates and your non-repeating command as needed.

Setup should look similar to this:
[image: Setup][1]]
[image: Setup][2]]
[image: Setup][3]]

Comment: Have you even tested that yourself? It always executes, no matter where you are, because `x=`, `y=` and `z=` just shift the search position. You could use a radius from there, but then you're back at the problem of the question.

Comment: I'll test this and some modifications when I get home from work but right now I don't have access to a computer with Minecraft installed

Comment: Same for me. The real solution is ˋ@a[x=?,y=?,z=?,dx=?,dy=?,dz=?]ˋ, but the question marks replaced with some accurate decimal numbers. I'll find those numbers in about 2 weeks when my laptop is back, but you can also try it (and get the points) if you have access to Minecraft earlier than that.

Comment: @FabianRöling no need for decimals! dx and dz can = 0. I set dy to 1 for safety but should still work

Comment: Sure, it **can** be 0, but then that wouldn't answer the question...

Comment: @FabianRöling setting to 0 seemed to work for me to a degree. I'm not convinced you can get more precisely centered on the block than "one pixel of your character is on the block and that's good enough to activate"

Comment: Oh no, in your latest edited you even use redstone for command blocks! That is already discouraged since 1.9 and never necessary since 1.13.

Comment: @FabianRöling it is? I couldn't find another way to get the second block to fire without including it in the first one which would cause it to repeat as long as the condition was true which may not be good for all purposes

Comment: but perhaps this would be better done in a chat to avoid a long comment discussion

Comment: I prefer mails, because I get instant notifications: fabianroeling@googlemail.com The part of only triggering once was not in the question. It can be done in various ways, like setting the `auto` tag of the command block to `0` or checking for some other condition and then changing that (like a tag, scoreboard, existence of an entity, etc.).